# SQL Delete from multiple tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have six tables and I would like to delete the data from these six tables in one query. Is it possible?

The **employee** table holds the primary key --> **emp_id**.
The other five tables **education**, **family**, **health**, **training** and **work** each holds **emp_id** as their foreign key.

I've tried this sql below. There's no error shown however the data is still in the database. Please help me as I'm new to this. Thanks

Query :

```
DELETE employee, family, education, work, training, health 
 FROM employee INNER JOIN family ON employee.emp_id=family.emp_id 
 INNER JOIN education ON employee.emp_id=education.emp_id 
 INNER JOIN work ON employee.emp_id=work.emp_id 
 INNER JOIN training ON employee.emp_id=training.emp_id 
 INNER JOIN health ON employee.emp_id=health.emp_id
 WHERE employee.emp_id='$id'
```

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do it all in one query? If it's only for data consistency for other sessions reading from these tables at the same time, I imagine multiple queries in a single transaction work for you. (Note I've also heard in the past that delete query like this with many joins can be very bad for performance and it's best to avoid that kind of thing if you can)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
DELETE table1
      ,table2 
  FROM table1
      ,table2 
 WHERE table1.columni = table2.columnj
   AND table1.columni = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not possible in SQL Server. You can enforce a cascade constrain between tables and make a single delete